# Years that the term "L'Ottocento" refers to?

Tags: meaning, numbers

From what I understand, "L'Ottocento" refers to the English equivalent of the 19th century (1801-1900). Is there a specific reason or any additional context as to why this term would refer to the 1800s and not the 800s as its literal translation would imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Luca Serianni in section VI.21 of his book *Italiano*, the expression "l'Ottocento" can also be used for 9th century, *ante* or *post Christum natum*, depending on the context. This is what is explained in the book:

> Nei numerali usati per i secoli dall'XI
> in poi può mancare la cifra delle migliaia.
> («il '300») o, in lettere, la parola *mille* («il
> Trecento»; si potrebbe pensare anche al
> IV secolo, prima o dopo Cristo: ma sarà il
> contesto a decidere). Nella sequenza di
> più centinaia indicanti secoli si può omettere *cento* nel primo membro (o nei primi
> membri) della serie: «un lirico italiano del
> Cinque o dell'Ottocento» (Leopardi, cit.
> in PASQUALI 1968: 172).

My translation:

> In the numerals used for the centuries from the 11th onwards, the thousands figure may be missing («il '300») or, if written in letters, the word *mille* can be omitted ("il Trecento"; one could also think of the 4th century, *ante* or *post Christum natum*: the context will decide). In the sequence of several "hundreds" indicating centuries the word *cento* can be omitted in the first member (or in the first members) of the sequence: "un lirico italiano del Cinque o dell'Ottocento" (Leopardi, quoted in PASQUALI 1968: 172).